# OpenGL ES 2.0 X-Axis is Flipped?

Tags: java, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I started drawing my Quad but when I started playing around with the Vertices I noticed that the X Coordinates are flipped. Heres a picture to show what I mean:

[image]

Here are my Vertices - Indices and Texture Coordinates which I don't really have to show.

```
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float positionCoords[] = { 
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   // top left
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f }; // top right

static final int COORDS_PER_TEXTURE = 2;
static float textureCoords[] = { 
    0.0f, 0.0f, 
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, };

private final short indices[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

And this is where I change the Projection and View Matrices.

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 naGl, int width, int height)
{
        Log.d(TAG, "GL Surface Changed - Setting Up View");

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;

    Matrix.frustumM(ProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

    Matrix.setLookAtM(ViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
}
```

Why would it be drawn 'backwards'. I also thought that my Camera might be behind the object so that in 3 dimensional space left would be positive if I'm behind the object.

Comment: I assume you mean X coordinates? (horizontal axis).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are indeed looking at the object from the reverse side.

Your lookAt function is placing the eye at (0,0,-3), and the lookAt point at (0, 0, 0). By default the negative z axis points into the screen, but you're looking at it from the reverse direction (towards the positive z axis).

You should have your eye at (0,0,3) looking toward (0,0,0) to get the view that you expect.

You may find [this chapter](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) of the Red Book informative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to openGL and I got the same problem. I've looked for hours on how to solve it. Your explanation are really clear and fix the problem. Thanks